# How to customize the Dice Loss function to replace the nll_loss function in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, customization, loss-function, semantic-segmentation, imbalanced-data

I assume the prediction result is `pred` and the corresponding label variable is `label_face`. Because the variable `label_face` contains a large amount of data imbalance in the segmentation problem. Therefore, I want to use the `Dice Loss` function to replace `nll_loss` in PyTorch.

```
pred = tensor([[-0.6813, -0.7052],
              [-0.6467, -0.7419], 
              [-0.7436, -0.6451],
              ...,
              [-0.5635, -0.8421],
              [-0.6089, -0.7852],
              [-0.7449, -0.6439]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>)

pred.shape --> torch.Size([7862, 2])

label_face = tensor([1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1], device='cuda:0')
label_face.shape --> torch.Size([7862])


loss = F.nll_loss(pred, label_face)        
loss.backward()
```

And I tried the custom Dice Loss for binary segmentation function as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.cuda.amp as amp


## Soft Dice Loss for binary segmentation
## pytorch autograd

class SoftDiceLoss(nn.Module):
    '''
    soft-dice loss, useful in binary segmentation
    '''
    def __init__(self,
                 p=1,
                 smooth=1):
        super(SoftDiceLossV1, self).__init__()
        self.p = p
        self.smooth = smooth

    def forward(self, logits, labels):
        '''
        inputs:
            logits: tensor of shape (N, H, W, ...)
            label: tensor of shape(N, H, W, ...)
        output:
            loss: tensor of shape(1, )
        '''
        probs = torch.sigmoid(logits)
        numer = (probs * labels).sum()
        denor = (probs.pow(self.p) + labels.pow(self.p)).sum()
        loss = 1. - (2 * numer + self.smooth) / (denor + self.smooth)
        return loss

custom_loss = SoftDiceLoss()
loss = custom_loss(pred, label_face)        
loss.backward()
```

I've really tried but can't do it or don't know where the error is. I am a beginner student, I hope you can help me with the code to customize this loss function. Any comments are highly appreciated. Thank you so much.